# Do we need a transit visa for Serbia?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, uae, serbia

Do we need a transit visa for Serbia for our connecting flight. We're flying from India to Germany with connections in both the UAE and in Belgrade. The layover time in Belgrade is less than 2 hours. We have a German student visa valid for 90 days.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&selDest=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20destination%28s%29%20above&TR=RS&selTrans=Serbia&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of confirmed onward tickets
>   for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

So no, you do **not** need a visa